# Implementing AJAX in Sharepoint

Tags: ajax, sharepoint

I am trying to implement Ajax in SharePoint.
I have installed AJAX extensions 1.0 in MOSS2007 but I am not able to find the extensions in my SharePoint Designer.
Can anyone help me in this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Setting up SharePoint to work with the MS Ajax controls is possible - I've done it before, but it does require various web config changes and some hacks in the code of the parent web part - something you are unlikely to be given access to do on a production system if you are working with SharePoint designer.

JQuery is probably a better option - you can put the script in a document library and it makes working directly with javascript a lot easier.

Calling the standard sharepoint web services from javascript works quite well - I recently posted some sample code on my blog that you may find helpful.

http://tqcblog.com/2009/05/04/sharepoint-discussion-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible. MS Ajax requires a specific doctype to exist in the header, but Sharepoint does not provide it.

The solution for you, my friend, can be found [here](http://jquery.com/).