# AJAX Control Toolkit Collapsible Panel in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to use the AJAX collapsible panel inside a user control which is loaded onto a Webpart in an AJAX enabled SharePoint site. I don't have any issues with using AJAX overal but I am having issues with this control. When the page loads, it does not collapse and when I click on the link to collapse/expand it just blinks and won't collapse. After a bit of reseach, I found that others have the same issue and a couple of people suggested to enclose the content panel in:

```
<div style="height:0px;position:absolute;" >
<asp:Panel> content </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

Doing that would fix the collapse issue but I think it defeats the purpose since you can't put anything underneath the panel or else it loads on top. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint 2007 runs in "Quirks Mode" due to the specific DocType that is implements, which causes the AJAX control toolkit to behave erratically.  (If you think you can update the sharepoint master page to have the "Transitional" doctype which causes the AJAX control toolkit to behave correctly, then various SharePoint pages will start breaking)

See below:

[Implementing AJAX in Sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827606/implementing-ajax-in-sharepoint)

Some AJAX Control Toolkit controls will work correctly.  Some of them will only work after hacking some of the  AJAX Control Toolkit source code for the controls you are interested in and compiling a new binary.  I've done this before but not without headaches.  It's better to just use JQuery were possible I think.